# Unable to parse XML data - possible casting issue

Tags: xml, soap, extract

I have the following SOAP XML file and trying to extract the 1Z tracking number.   Unfortunately, I only get a null value back.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  xmlns:v1="http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/UPSS/v1.0" xmlns:v3="http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/Track/v2.0" xmlns:v11="http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/Common/v1.0">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <v1:UPSSecurity>
            <v1:UsernameToken>
                <v1:Username>abc123@xyz.com</v1:Username>
                <v1:Password>password1</v1:Password>
            </v1:UsernameToken>
            <v1:ServiceAccessToken>
                <v1:AccessLicenseNumber>50FF35A3061C</v1:AccessLicenseNumber>
            </v1:ServiceAccessToken>
        </v1:UPSSecurity>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <v3:TrackRequest>
            <v3:InquiryNumber>1ZA1059V0300434532</v3:InquiryNumber>
        </v3:TrackRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I'm trying to extract the tracking number from the above XML but having casting issues.

```
package com.ups.xolt.codesamples;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;


public class Parser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder builder;
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = builder.parse("TrackRequest.xml");

            // Create XPathFactory object
            XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();

            // Create XPath object
            XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();

            String InquiryNumber = getInquiryNumber(doc, xpath);
            System.out.println("InquiryNumber: " + InquiryNumber);

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private static String  getInquiryNumber(Document doc, XPath xpath) {
        String InquiryNumber = null;
       // List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
       // xpath.setNamespaceContext(arg0);
         try {
            XPathExpression expr =
                xpath.compile("//soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/v3:TrackRequest/v3:InquiryNumber/text()" );
            InquiryNumber = (String) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING);
          //  NodeList nodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

        //    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++)
        //        list.add(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());
        } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return InquiryNumber;
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elements in the SOAP XML are bound to namespaces. You are referencing namespace-prefixes in your XPath, but you have not registered any of the namespaces that should correspond to those namespace-prefixes.

You need to configure the namespaces with a [`NamespaceContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/namespace/NamespaceContext.html) and then set the context on your XPath object with [`xpath.setNamespaceContext()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLEventWriter.html#setNamespaceContext-javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext-)

```
NamespaceContext context = new NamespaceContextMap(
    "soapenv", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", 
    "v3", "http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/Track/v2.0");
xpath.setNamespaceContext(context);
```